# Send intent from listview to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am working on an app where I am useing a `PackageManager` to import all the package names on the device using this code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
    ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
    ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                         activity.name);
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);


    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
               Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);

    startActivity(i);    
}
```

This code manage to start the app from a `ListView`. But I want to send the app details to another class to start it from there instead of starting it from this class. Then I want the result to be saved but changeable by clicking on another app later.

Are there any ways of doing this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why starting an activity like this is not sufficient? Why do you need to start it from another class?

Comment: I am making an app where I make a shortcut to the selected app.

Comment: Doesn't this code launch the other app? It still isn't clear what the problem is.

Comment: The point is that you do not need to scroll and click on the app, but you only need to press a button witch uses starts an activity that tries to launch the shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select the app from the list and start it using a separate button click, then how about storing the activity.applicationInfo.packageName and activity.name to ***SharedPreferences*** once list item is selected. In case the user select other item from the list overwrite the ***SharedPreferences*** parameters.

When the start button is clicked read these parameters and launch the app.

Comment: what Sharedpref? [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 0):

How about binding to a service, sending a message to that service, and the service will start the activity?
Or registering a broadcast receiver, sending an intent to that receiver, with the requested application as extra information, and having the broadcast receiver do the work?

Comment: I found a nice tutorial for you: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571564/android-pendingintent-extras-not-received-by-broadcastreceiver/14612215#14612215